# parsing document in with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, json, parsing

I need to parse this json with javascript

```
    {
     "MasterProducts": {
    "MasterProduct": [
      {
        "Productcode": "0903-000192",
        "Description": "ICROCOMPUTER;32FX200 24BIT QFP 132P",
        "ThumbPic": "NoImage.png",
        "RRP": "41.400000",
        "Stock": "0"
      },
      {
        "Productcode": "0160-030",
        "Description": "AXIS MPEG-4 Decoder 50-user licence pack onto 50 separate computers. For all Axis MPEG-4 products that do not support AAC audio encoding. (210 211 210A 211A 213 214 221 225FD 231D+ 232D+ 241S 241Q 241SA 241QA 242SIV 243SA 282 282A).",
        "ThumbPic": "NoImage.png",
        "RRP": "35.230000",
        "Stock": "0"
      },
      {
        "Productcode": "0160-040",
        "Description": "AXIS MPEG-4 +ACC Decoder 50-user license onto 50 separate computers. For all Axis products that supports MPEG-4. (207 207W 207MW 212PTZ 216FD 223M).",
        "ThumbPic": "NoImage.png",
        "RRP": "50.880000",
        "Stock": "0"
      },
      {
        "Productcode": "10403E",
        "Description": "Hotsync palm computer cradle/docking station",
        "ThumbPic": "NoImage.png",
        "RRP": "0.000000",
        "Stock": "2"
      },
      {
        "Productcode": "0903-000193",
        "Description": "ICROCOMPUTER;32FX200 24BIT QFP 132P",
        "ThumbPic": "NoImage.png",
        "RRP": "37.790000",
        "Stock": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have managed to do it when it's only one result with this code

```
 if(data !== '')
    {
        xmlData = data.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].data;
        objData = app.XML2OBJ(xmlData);            
        var item = objData.MasterProduct.Description;
        //alert(item);
    }
```

But can't get it to work with multiple sets of results.

Comment: ... but why? JSON can be accessed from JavaScript, theres a reason its called JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) :)

Comment: @Jeff: Javascript Serialized Object Notation

Comment: Oh, my bad - I always read it as JavaScript Object Notation

Comment: @Jeff it's actually *JavaScript* Object Notation.

Comment: Yes I can access the data in the first set of results but how do I handle this when I don't know how many set of results will be returned

Comment: Jeff was right the first time. See [the specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) and [the homepage](http://json.org/). There is no "Serialized" in the name.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought, but was too lazy to google it just to support my memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people have been discussing in the comments above, you can simply use normal vanilla JavaScript to access the data.

```
var data = // JSON 

console.log(data.MasterProducts.MasterProduct[0].Productcode);
```

Will give you `0903-000192`. Objects that contain square brackets `[]` are arrays. For them you can use the array notation of `arr[0]`. For objects, you can use their key names.

```
{
"MasterProducts": {
 "MasterProduct": [
   {
     "Productcode": "0903-000192",
     "Description": "ICROCOMPUTER;32FX200 24BIT QFP 132P",
     "ThumbPic": "NoImage.png",
     "RRP": "41.400000",
     "Stock": "0"
   }
 ]
}
```

`MasterProducts` is your root object, so you can use it as your entry point.

```
var products = data.MasterProducts;
```

Now, to get the first element of the list of products you could use array notation.

```
products.MasterProduct[0]
```

To get at one of the properties of that element, you could then again use the dot notation -

```
products.MasterProduct[0].Description //"ICROCOMPUTER;32FX200 24BIT QFP 132P"
```

Comment: I have tried this below but it doesn't give me the data. 

objData = app.XML2OBJ(data);
var item = objData.MasterProducts;
alert(item.MasterProduct[0].Description);

Comment: You don't need to use `XML2OBJ`. The data is already in a format that you can use.

Comment: This is so frustrating, I feel like it should be working but it isn't. My webservice returns an xml which my application-craft IDE automatically converts to JSON (according to documentation). So I don't understand why it still doesn't work. The error is Cannot read property 'MasterProduct' of undefined : undefined

Comment: @ama - Take a look at this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qTfNh/). You can see I'm not using any thing other than normal JavaScript to loop through all the products or access one directly.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to parse it, JSON is how JavaScript Objects are made.

```
// alerting each product description:
for(var product in data.MasterProducts.MasterProduct){
    // "product" is the current iteration in the products array
    alert(product.Description);
    // You can access all the product properties here.
    alert(product.Productcode);
}
```

That should do it. Now, say theres a chance only 1 master product is returned, then the MasterProducts property is not an array, but an object, and the for loop above will probably break. The easiest way to prevent this is to concat the MasterProducts into an empty array, before looping. There may be a slight perf penalty, but I dont really think its that critical at all.

```
// Concat to empty array first
data.MasterProducts.MasterProduct = [].concat(data.MasterProducts.MasterProduct);
// alerting each product description:
for(var product in data.MasterProducts.MasterProduct){
    // "product" is the current iteration in the products array
    alert(product.Description);
    // You can access all the product properties here.
    alert(product.Productcode);
}
```

I wrote my answer as a loop because I asume you want to process all the products.
In case you just want to access the first product, then you can access the products array:

```
data.MasterProducts.MasterProduct[0].Description
```

Comment: why have you used product.Description?

Comment: Are you asking why I use **product**.Description, or product.**Description**?

Comment: I have edited my answer with a note explaining why I use **product**.Description

Answer (score 0):

json is native to javascript - no need for parser.

But I'll show you how using NPEG you can parse **any type** of document including json.

## Parsing a document with javascript

You could also use
https://github.com/leblancmeneses/NPEG/tree/master/Languages/npeg_javascript

Here is a visual tool that can export C version: http://www.robusthaven.com/blog/parsing-expression-grammar/npeg-language-workbench

Documentation for rule grammar: http://www.robusthaven.com/blog/parsing-expression-grammar/npeg-dsl-documentation

Rules

```
    S: [\s]*;
(?<StringValue>):  '"' (?<String> [^"]+) '"' / "'" (?<String> [^']+) "'";
(?<NumberValue>):  [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)?;

(?<KeyValuePair>): ( '"'  (?<Key>[^"]+) '"' / "'" (?<Key> [^']+) "'" ) S ':' S  (StringValue / NumberValue / ValueRecursive) S;
(?<Object>): '{' S ( S  KeyValuePair S  ','? )*  S '}'; 
(?<Array>): '[' S (  S Object S  ','? )* S ']';
ValueRecursive: Array / Object ;
(?<JSON>): S ValueRecursive S;
```

Input  i tried:
This SO question and first input on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON .